# What makes Euclidian space univalent and topological space multivalent?

Tags: axioms, philosophy

Here is a quote from wikipedia:

> Euclidean axioms leave no freedom, they determine uniquely all
>   geometric properties of the space. More exactly: all three-dimensional
>   **Euclidean spaces are mutually isomorphic. In this sense we have "the"
>   three-dimensional Euclidean space**. In terms of Bourbaki, the
>   corresponding theory is univalent. In contrast, topological spaces are
>   generally non-isomorphic, their theory is multivalent. A similar idea
>   occurs in mathematical logic: a theory is called categorical if all
>   its models of the same cardinality are mutually isomorphic. According
>   to Bourbaki,[5] the study of multivalent theories is the most striking
>   feature which distinguishes modern mathematics from classical
>   mathematics

What is the underlying argument here?

What makes it so that we can speak of **the** Euclidian space?

Answer (score 2):

When using axiom to specify what one wants to talk about, there are generally *two* possible intentions behind this:

1. One can use axioms to try specifying *one and only one* structure. One tries to find the axioms which describe the wanted object uniquely, pin it down to study the properties of it and nothing else. This, for example, was the intention for construction the **Euclidean space** (e.g. using Tarski's axioms). The axioms were chosen in a way so that any other structure satisfying them too is 
   essentially the same thing (i.e. isomorphic). In the case of Euclidean space this was successful. This is why we *can* speak of *the* Euclidean space. But it does not work for everything we can think about. According to Gödel's incompleteness theorem it is not possible to pin down the natural numbers uniquely. There will always be non-isomorphic objects that satisfy Peanos's axioms equally well. Even tho the intention is the same here, it is damned to fail. This however does not prevent most of the mathematicians to talk about *the* natural numbers. It seems the intention is leading here.
2. On the other hand, axioms can be used to only vaguely describe what one wants to talk about. Maybe we want to study a whole class of objects at the same time. For example, if I do not only want to study the Euclidean space, but want to find any theorem that is true in any Euclidean geometry in general, i.e. in any dimensions. Those axioms must leave room for several objects, here for general $n$-dimensional spaces for any $n\in \Bbb N$. And this happends all the time. Mathematicians love to study several objects at the same time, because they love the general applicability of their tools. The axioms of group theory are so vague, that they can describe all kind of number spaces, vector spaces, finite and infinite objects, Rubic's cubes, particle physics, etc. There is not ***the*** **topological space** because it was the *intention* to let room for all kinds of spaces that behave in a specific similar way. Take any Euclidean geometry, it is a topological space. Any theorem proven for topological spaces must hold in any dimension. But also spheres, tori, lines, dots, actually any set can be used to build a topological space and can be studied by using the same few axioms.

In short, the resason why we can say *the* Euclidean space but not *the* topological space is because the former system (theory) was designed to only fit to a single object (and it was proven that this is the case) while the latter was designed to fit a whole class of structures. It is all about the intention.

And I believe the shift in modern mathematics to the second way is because of the discovery of the power of generalization. As made clear above, in this way it is possible to describe myriads of seemingly different objects inside a single theory. We can prove things for the natural numbers and the Euclidean space in a single theorem, while in the past these two fields are mostly distinct and have to be studied seperately.